# OSX Remote Screen Sharing But No SOCKS

Tags: macos, mac, ssh-tunnel, socks

Edit2: I *think* it's a DNS issue on the remote machine, but I'm not completely sure.  Once I've set up the SOCKS proxy via `ssh -D 5050 -C -N user@remote.com` and fired up Firefox pointed to 5050, *some* IP addresses that I put in directly get me to a page.  E.g. `104.16.155.36` gets me a response from Cloudfare (that they don't like direct IP access).  Others don't work, e.g. `74.125.230.243` (supposed to be Google).  As far as I can tell I flushed my DNS by following https://phoenixnap.com/kb/how-to-flush-dns-cache using `sudo dscacheutil -flushcache` followed by `sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder` since the remote machine is running Mavericks.  Didn't help.  If I change the DNS servers in the Advanced section of Network to `208.67.222.220`, `208.67.222.222`, `8.8.8.8`, and `8.8.4.4`, then I can get to [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) and even perform searches.  But clicking on links doesn't seem to work: I can see some data going back and forth, and the title of the page in the tab changes correctly, but generally nothing displays or it takes a *hideously* long time (many minutes) for a simple page to load.  Any further ideas?  Many thanks!!

Edited: I've now managed to successfully set up a SOCKS proxy through another home network using a different Mac laptop (running 10.13.6) as the remote ssh server.  I'm very confused as to why the below doesn't just work out of the box.  Ideally, I'd try the working remote Mac laptop server on my home network, but this is physically impossible at the moment.  I thought that maybe something is blocking outbound ssh on my home network, but I can easily ssh into the remote laptop on my home network and then ssh from there to another server on a different network.  Again, any pointers or ideas would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

I would like to use my home network as a VPN.

I've done similar things with servers (maintained by much smarter people than me) I have access to using a SOCKS proxy simply by using `ssh -D 5050 -C -N user@remote.com` then using Firefox with a manual localhost SOCKS proxy on port 5050.

By generally following https://www.tech-otaku.com/networking/establishing-ssh-tunnel-remotely-access-mac-afp-vnc/, I've set up my home router (connected to the internet via Spectrum, in case that matters) and an old Mac laptop (running OSX 10.9.5) in such a way that I can successfully 1) ssh into the remote old Mac laptop and 2) even Screen Share the old Mac laptop using `ssh -f user@remote.dynamic-dns.net -L 15900:127.0.0.1:5900 sleep 60` followed by running `vnc://127.0.0.1:15900` on the Screen Sharing application.

When I try to just ssh tunnel like before, Firefox doesn't do anything and ultimately times out.

Any help would be ***greatly*** appreciated.

If it's of help, using `ssh -D 5050 -C -N user@remote.dynamic-dns.net -vvv` I get the following after entering my password (where I've removed the addresses for privacy):

> debug3: send packet: type 61
> debug3: receive packet: type 60
> debug2: input_userauth_info_req
> debug2: input_userauth_info_req: num_prompts 0
> debug3: send packet: type 61
> debug3: receive packet: type 52
> debug1: Enabling compression at level 6.
> debug1: Authentication succeeded (keyboard-interactive).
> Authenticated to remote.dynamic-dns.net ([IPaddress]:22).
> debug1: Local connections to LOCALHOST:5050 forwarded to remote address socks:0
> debug3: channel_setup_fwd_listener_tcpip: type 2 wildcard 0 addr NULL
> debug1: Local forwarding listening on 127.0.0.1 port 5050.
> debug2: fd 7 setting O_NONBLOCK
> debug3: fd 7 is O_NONBLOCK
> debug1: channel 0: new [port listener]
> debug3: sock_set_v6only: set socket 8 IPV6_V6ONLY
> debug1: Local forwarding listening on ::1 port 5050.
> debug2: fd 8 setting O_NONBLOCK
> debug3: fd 8 is O_NONBLOCK
> debug1: channel 1: new [port listener]
> debug2: fd 4 setting TCP_NODELAY
> debug3: ssh_packet_set_tos: set IP_TOS 0x48
> debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
> debug3: send packet: type 80
> debug1: Entering interactive session.
> debug1: pledge: network

Once I try to use Firefox, I get the following:

> debug1: Connection to port 5050 forwarding to socks port 0 requested.
> debug2: fd 9 setting TCP_NODELAY
> debug3: fd 9 is O_NONBLOCK
> debug3: fd 9 is O_NONBLOCK
> debug1: channel 2: new [dynamic-tcpip]
> debug2: channel 2: pre_dynamic: have 0
> debug2: channel 2: pre_dynamic: have 3
> debug2: channel 2: decode socks5
> debug2: channel 2: socks5 auth done
> debug2: channel 2: pre_dynamic: need more
> debug2: channel 2: pre_dynamic: have 0
> debug2: channel 2: pre_dynamic: have 33
> debug2: channel 2: decode socks5
> debug2: channel 2: socks5 post auth
> debug2: channel 2: dynamic request: socks5 host mozilla.cloudflare-dns.com port 443 command 1
> debug3: send packet: type 90

Where it then sits for a long time on Terminal, then repeats for channels 3 - 7, then I get

> debug1: Connection to port 5050 forwarding to socks port 0 requested.
> debug2: fd 15 setting TCP_NODELAY
> debug3: fd 15 is O_NONBLOCK
> debug3: fd 15 is O_NONBLOCK
> debug1: channel 8: new [dynamic-tcpip]
> debug2: channel 8: pre_dynamic: have 0
> debug1: Connection to port 5050 forwarding to socks port 0 requested.
> debug2: fd 16 setting TCP_NODELAY
> debug3: fd 16 is O_NONBLOCK
> debug3: fd 16 is O_NONBLOCK
> debug1: channel 9: new [dynamic-tcpip]
> debug2: channel 8: pre_dynamic: have 3
> debug2: channel 8: decode socks5
> debug2: channel 8: socks5 auth done
> debug2: channel 8: pre_dynamic: need more
> debug2: channel 9: pre_dynamic: have 0
> debug2: channel 8: pre_dynamic: have 0
> debug2: channel 9: pre_dynamic: have 3
> debug2: channel 9: decode socks5
> debug2: channel 9: socks5 auth done
> debug2: channel 9: pre_dynamic: need more
> debug2: channel 8: pre_dynamic: have 0
> debug2: channel 9: pre_dynamic: have 0
> debug2: channel 8: pre_dynamic: have 26
> debug2: channel 8: decode socks5
> debug2: channel 8: socks5 post auth
> debug2: channel 8: dynamic request: socks5 host spocs.getpocket.com port 443 command 1
> debug3: send packet: type 90
> debug2: channel 9: pre_dynamic: have 0
> debug2: channel 9: pre_dynamic: have 32
> debug2: channel 9: decode socks5
> debug2: channel 9: socks5 post auth
> debug2: channel 9: dynamic request: socks5 host getpocket.cdn.mozilla.net port 443 command 1
> debug3: send packet: type 90
> debug3: receive packet: type 91
> debug2: channel 6: open confirm rwindow 2097152 rmax 32768
> debug3: receive packet: type 91
> debug2: channel 8: open confirm rwindow 2097152 rmax 32768
> debug2: channel 8: read<=0 rfd 15 len 0
> debug2: channel 8: read failed
> debug2: channel 8: chan_shutdown_read (i0 o0 sock 15 wfd 15 efd -1 [closed])
> debug2: channel 8: input open -> drain
> debug2: channel 8: ibuf empty
> debug2: channel 8: send eof
> debug3: send packet: type 96
> debug2: channel 8: input drain -> closed
> debug3: receive packet: type 96
> debug2: channel 8: rcvd eof
> debug2: channel 8: output open -> drain
> debug2: channel 8: obuf empty
> debug2: channel 8: chan_shutdown_write (i3 o1 sock 15 wfd 15 efd -1 [closed])
> debug2: channel 8: output drain -> closed
> debug3: receive packet: type 97
> debug2: channel 8: rcvd close
> debug3: channel 8: will not send data after close
> debug2: channel 8: send close
> debug3: send packet: type 97
> debug2: channel 8: is dead
> debug2: channel 8: garbage collecting
> debug1: channel 8: free: direct-tcpip: listening port 5050 for spocs.getpocket.com port 443, connect from 127.0.0.1 port 63562 to 127.0.0.1 port 5050, nchannels 10
> debug3: channel 8: status: The following connections are open:
> #2 direct-tcpip: listening port 5050 for whatismyipaddress.com port 443, connect from 127.0.0.1 port 63539 to 127.0.0.1 port 5050 (t3 nr0 i0/0 o0/10 e[closed]/0 fd 9/9/-1 sock 9 cc -1)
> #3 direct-tcpip: listening port 5050 for whatismyipaddress.com port 443, connect from 127.0.0.1 port 63540 to 127.0.0.1 port 5050 (t3 nr0 i0/0 o0/10 e[closed]/0 fd 10/10/-1 sock 10 cc -1)
> #4 direct-tcpip: listening port 5050 for mozilla.cloudflare-dns.com port 443, connect from 127.0.0.1 port 63541 to 127.0.0.1 port 5050 (t3 nr0 i0/0 o0/10 e[closed]/0 fd 11/11/-1 sock 11 cc -1)
> #5 direct-tcpip: listening port 5050 for mozilla.cloudflare-dns.com port 443, connect from 127.0.0.1 port 63542 to 127.0.0.1 port 5050 (t3 nr0 i0/0 o0/10 e[closed]/0 fd 12/12/-1 sock 12 cc -1)
> #6 direct-tcpip: listening port 5050 for spocs.getpocket.com port 443, connect from 127.0.0.1 port 63560 to 127.0.0.1 port 5050 (t4 r4 i0/0 o0/2304 e[closed]/0 fd 13/13/-1 sock 13 cc -1)

and things appear to repeat again thereafter.

My vague sense is that I need to adjust something on the remote old Mac laptop; in order to get the ssh and screen sharing to work, following the above link I had to make changes to Sharing to allow screen sharing and remote login.  Under Internet Sharing in Sharing, the only options I have are FireWire and Ethernet.  Allowing Internet Sharing through Ethernet doesn't help.

Again, thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I absolutely have no real idea of *why* this works, but following https://bugzilla.mindrot.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1357 I changed `#AddressFamily any` in etc/sshd_config to `AddressFamily inet`, which resolved the issue.